# How to configure different langage for Pentaho data Table

Tags: datatables, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I have used pentaho (biserver-ce-6.1.0.1-196) for report development. Now I want to changes pagination panel language. That is using jquery dataTable.

jquery datatable configuration document here:-
https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/language_file.html

Now I need to know, how to configure those different language in pentaho CDE server UI level.

Comment: I have added inside language option in pentaho following code segment.       {
    "url": "/pentaho/custom/language/en.json"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the data table is inside the table component, what you could do is create the JSON of the internationalization and upload it to the server, and see the resource to put it in the URL, the other way is to create a js file, where the properties of the table language are overwritten, for example

var messages={
"sProcessing": "Procesando...",
"sLengthMenu": "Mostrar *MENU* entradas",
"sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
"sInfo": "Mostrando: *START* - *END* de: *TOTAL* resultados",
"sInfoEmpty": "Sin datos",
"sInfoFiltered": "(*MAX* filtrados)",
"sInfoPostFix": "",
"sSearch": "Buscar:",
"sUrl": "",
"oPaginate": {
"sFirst": "Primer",
"sPrevious": "Anterior",
"sNext": "Siguiente",
"sLast": "Último"
}
}

This file is put as resource and it is called in the configuration of the table, I hope it helps you, greetings